# renderIUI not working in Shiny Modules in R

Tags: r, module, shiny, shinydashboard

I have made a simple app in Shiny using shinydashboard and data from gapminder. The basic version is working, but I can not devide it into modules.

The app is plotting a histogram basing on user choices:

- the continent from the list (all continents available in data) 
  and
- the country (countries are filtered on the basis on the selected continent)

The code and screen are below.
app:

```
    library(gapminder)
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(dplyr)

    ui <- dashboardPage(

    skin = "yellow",
    dashboardHeader(
    title = "gapminder - data",
    titleWidth = 300
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 300,
    sidebarMenu(
      id="menu",

      uiOutput("continent"),
      uiOutput("country")

    )
  ),


  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("plot")
    ))
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    all_data <- filter(gapminder, country != "Kuwait")
    all_data
  })

  output$continent <- renderUI({

    data <- data()
    selectInput("continent",
                "CONTINENT:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                choices = sort(unique(data$continent)))
  })


  output$country <- renderUI({

    data <- data()
    ct <- input$continent

    data %>%
      filter(continent == ct) %>%
      .$country %>%
      unique() %>%
      as.character() -> names

    selectInput("country",
                "COUNTRY:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                choices = names)
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    data <- data()
    ct <- input$continent
    co <- input$country

    data %>%
    filter(continent == ct,
           country == co) %>%
      .$lifeExp ->selected_data


  histogram <- hist(selected_data)
  histogram

})

}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

I want to rewrite it using Shiny Modules - putting the dropdown fields in separated modules. I recived an error like this:

[image]

The code to the modified app (with modules) is:

```
library(gapminder)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)

source("global.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(

  skin = "yellow",

  dashboardHeader(
    title = "gapminder - data",
    titleWidth = 300
  ),

  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 300,

    sidebarMenu(
      id="menu",

      gapModuleUI("all")

    ) ),


  dashboardBody(

    fluidRow(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  callModule(gapModule, "all")

  data <- reactive({
    all_data <- filter(gapminder, country != "Kuwait")
    all_data
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({

    data <- data()
    ct <- input$continent
    co <- input$country

    data %>%
      filter(continent == ct,
             country == co) %>%
      .$lifeExp ->selected_data


    histogram <- hist(selected_data)
    histogram

  })

}
# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And modules are in global.R:

```
gapModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tagList(

    uiOutput(ns("continent")),

    uiOutput(ns("country"))
  )
}

gapModule <- function(input, output, session) {

  ns <- session$ns

  data <- reactive({
    all_data <- filter(gapminder, country != "Kuwait")
    all_data
  })

  output$continent <- renderUI({

    data <- data()

    selectInput(ns("continent"),
                "CONTINENT:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                choices = sort(unique(data$continent)))

    })


  output$country <- renderUI({

    data <- data()
    ct <- reactive({input$continent})

    data %>%
      filter(continent == ct) %>%
      .$country %>%
      unique() %>%
      as.character() -> names

    selectInputns(ns("country"),
                "COUNTRY:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                choices = names)
  })

}
```

What should I change in my modules?

Comment: In `ui` part try using `ns <- NS(id)` and then `gapModuleUI(ns("all"))` instead of `gapModuleUI("all")`

Comment: @potockan, in `ui` , you mean `ui <- dashboardPage(...`? Unfortunately, it's not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server part of the module when you render UI you also have to wrap ID in `ns`. To get it from `session` use `ns <- session$ns`.  Then:

```
  output$continent <- renderUI({

    data <- data()

    selectInput(ns("continent"),
                "CONTINENT:",
                multiple = FALSE,
                choices = sort(unique(data$continent)))

    })
```

Same with `output$country`

EDIT:
So three things:

1. In `global.R` change `filter(continent == ct) %>%` to `filter(continent == ct()) %>%`. `ct` is reactive function.
2. In `global.R` you have also a typo: change `selectInputns(ns("country"),` to `selectInput(ns("country"),`
3. In main file there is important thing. You try to use inputs from module outside this module: `ct <- input$continent` and `co <- input$country`. Module should be self contained but there is a way to get to them. `NS(id)` simply appends `"id-"` to everything it is applied to, ie.: `NS("MyId")("input") == "MyId-input"`. So if you want to use the module inputs you can do it in several ways:

   ```
   nsall <- NS("all")
   ct <- input[[nsall('continent')]]
   co <- input[[nsall('country')]]
   ```

   or

   ```
   ct <- input$`all-continent`
   co <- input$`all-country`
   ```

   or you can also make your `gapModule` return something:

   ```
   return(reactive(c(ct = input$continent, co = input$country)))
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   params <- callModule(gapModule, "all")
   ct <- params()['ct']
   co <- params()['co']
   ```

Comment: I have changed it, but now I have a new bug... Have a look, I have edited the code.